# How to check a purchase in Xamarin Forms InAppBilling plugin on Android?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, plugins, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I'm testing James Montemagno's **Xamarin in-app billing plugin** on my app with a beta version deployed to Google Play.

```
bool billingConnected = await billing.ConnectAsync();

if (!billingConnected)
    return (false, "Cannot connect.");

IEnumerable<InAppBillingPurchase> purchases = await billing.GetPurchasesAsync(ItemType.InAppPurchase);

//purchase not owned
if (purchases == null || purchases.Count() == 0)
{
    return (true, "Purchase not found");
}

purchase = purchases.FirstOrDefault(p => string.Compare(p.Id, PRODUCTID_ABC, true) == 0);

//purchase not owned
if (purchase == null)// THIS IS ALWAYS NULL
{
    return (true, "Purchase not found"); 
}
```

However, when I try to make a purchase following this, I get the error message:

- **PurchaseError.AlreadyOwned**

What is happening here?

I've read on the Google docs that some queries require setting up "access to the Google Play Developer API, [and] be sure that you've granted the View financial data permission...".

Is this what is relevant here. Is this what I'm missing? There is no mention of this however in James Montemagno's plugin documentation.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found my bug:

```
purchase = purchases.FirstOrDefault(p => string.Compare(p.Id, PRODUCTID_ABC, true) == 0);
```

should use `p.ProductId`, and not `p.Id`. The latter I believe is the transaction id.

This fixes the problem!